path issue showing while running flutter doctor command in cmd prompt
Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
X Cannot execute path_to_Java_17_home\bin\java to determine the version

How could I solve this error while running flutter doctor in cmd?
I need a solution. I added the path correctly and i checked it correct or not through commands, and I get the correct output but this issue still exists. I need a better solution for this.

you use windows? can you do java -version in your cmd?

yes i do the version and the output printed succesfully in cmd
